# Get-WmiObject : Invalid class "SoftwareLicensingProduct"

Tags: powershell

I'm new to powershell and am trying to write a program that will get the product key of numerous servers.

I am looping through the server names and trying to do the following code but am getting the error in the title

```
$LicenseInfo = Get-WmiObject -Class SoftwareLicensingProduct -ComputerName $target -Credential $cred  | ` 
Where-Object { $_.PartialProductKey -and $_.ApplicationID -eq "55c92734-d682-4d71-983e-d6ec3f16059f" } | Select-Object PartialProductKey, Description, ProductKeyChannel, @{ N = "LicenseStatus"; E = { $lstat["$($_.LicenseStatus)"] } }
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Did you try running it without any filtering? Have you tried using a wmi tool to see if your filtering actually works?

Comment: As per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/sppwmi/softwarelicensingproduct: Minimum supported client
__Windows 7__
Minimum supported server
__Windows Server 2008 R2__. Are you targetting a machine that does not fit that spec?

Answer (score 0):

That error is very specific. Are you targeting machines that do not have this class available? As per [learn.microsoft.com for SoftwareLicensingProduct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/sppwmi/softwarelicensingproduct):

> Minimum supported client: Windows 7
>
> Minimum supported server: Windows Server 2008 R2